# Apache Pig: lightweight java client

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a lightweight Java client for Apache Pig? There is basically only one artifact in Maven, `org.apache.pig:pig:0.10.1`, which is a very large jar (3 MB) with a whole lot of transitive dependencies. This is not going to work for us. We just need to talk to the Hadoop cluster to submit regularly scheduled Pig jobs. Are tools to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a PigServer class that you can access from java to start pig jobs. See [Run pig in java without embedding pig script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152068/run-pig-in-java-without-embedding-pig-script). As for maven, you can [exclude the dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to lessen the final size of the jar.

Comment: This is quite disappointing. The Pig Maven dependency pulls in a whole bunch of other dependencies which can be a problem when trying to integrate it in an existing project. Assuming I am able to exclude most of them, it seems like the only option is to have a local pig server instance which seems overkill when I am just trying to submit a job as from a dummy terminal. We resolved by submitting jobs with SSH instead. Hackish but it's fine for now.