# How to execute pig script from java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

How to execute pig script from java class.
I have installed pig on linux system and my java application on windows system.
Thanks

Comment: You can't run a pig script that exists on another computer. You need to copy that script into your code https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299259/2308683

Answer (score 0):

You have two options basically.

1) Execute spawn shell subprocess via Java API and handover Script to it.

2) Use Embedded pig Script. (I would prefer this one. as it gives good control over variables needed for operations.)